# How to have logout for a stateless RESTful API

Tags: rest, jwt

I'm working on a stateless RESTful API. For authentication, I'm currently planning on using JSON Web Tokens. I like their simplicity for the task.

My one challenge, however, is figuring out how I will log users out. On the one hand, the tokens will have timeouts, and once they are timed out boom, no longer valid, easy logout. But what if I want the user to be able to have a logout button that they can press to log them out.

This is where my desire to have a stateless server conflicts with what I'm trying to do. The only thing I can think of is having a value in my databasee, say a version #, that would be included in the JWT hash, and every login/logout, it gets changes. That way the hashes would no longer match. I'm just not sure if that's the most effective way to get the job done.

Comment: What is the server actually doing with the token other then authenticating the user and eventually limiting his access to certain resources? As the token has to be sent on every request, why should the server provide a logout-functionality, which contradicts the statelessnes constraint REST has.

Comment: @RomanVottner Actually https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token is stateless. The logged in status is maintained by the client, the server only adds a signature to the auth data, so it does not have to ask for username and password by every request. Instead it parses the token, checks the signature and accepts the data in the token.

Comment: @inf3rno Even if the server does not have to lookup the user in the DB again, the server will have to check the signature within the request and somehow trust it, which is also a form of authentication. Though, we divagate a bit. The logout in that case is simply executed by the client by removing the signature. The server does not have to remember a thing and therefore does not have to provide a logout-method IMO

Comment: @RomanVottner I just wanted to add the same in an answer. :-) Btw. I don't get why everybody tries to use REST by human - machine communication, it wasn't meant for that.

Comment: @inf3rno feel-free, I remove my comments then :)

Comment: @RomanVottner Nope, I have enough REST points, you should send it. :-)

Comment: @RomanVottner I like the direction you're going with this. It brings up another question I've been looking into, which is how the browser handles changes to the token. So let's say, on clicking logout in the client, the response to the browser contains the token with the signature stripped out. How will the browser handle the new token, vs its old copy of the token?